# TensorFlow - Text Classification using Neural Networks

Tags: text-classification, tensorflow

Is there any example on how can TensorFlow be used for text classification using neural networks?

Comment: Sumit asked the question on the Tensorflow github page and was told to come here.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/215

Comment: I'd like to see an example of this as well.

Answer (score 4):

I've started putting together a set of examples for text classification on DBPedia dataset (predicting class of object from its description) as part of examples for **Scikit Flow**:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py

Going to expand this example and write a blog post when will have enough different models showcased. Feel free to suggest other datasets and models you would be interested to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ilblackdragon.  I am able to make use of your example.  It will be great help if you can document the **rnn_model** function.

Comment: @SumitChawla I've added a bunch of comments in the example: https://github.com/google/skflow/blob/master/examples/text_classification.py and will try to write a blog post in close future about this types of the models. Let me know if you still have questions though.

Comment: How can we test the model. There is save and restore file but one sentence at a time. Any tutorial? Please help.

Comment: update to the URL: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification.py

Comment: It's here now :- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py

Answer (score 3):

Denny Britz has some great tutorials for Deep learning on his blog at [here](http://www.wildml.com)

and has an example on github [here](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf)

Some of his examples don't use tensor flow but the one I linked to github uses CNN for text classification using tensor flow